# How to retrieve the URL of the container parent using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
$(this).find('a:first');
```

and is working just fine to retrieve the URL of the first link, if the button I click is into the same container as the link I want to retrieve.

But how to retrieve the URL of the parent container?

In the bellow case, I want to retrieve the link of the a.sharedLink of the same `<li>` the buttons are in. So if someone is clicking on one of those buttons, onclick event will capture the URL of the a.sharedLink. I have all the entire functionality, all I want is just to get that URL.

e.g:

```
<ul class="links">
<li><a class="sharedLink" href="http://www.domain1.com">Check out my hilarious personal website! :)</a>
<span class="buttons">
    <a href="" class="share shareTW" target="_blank">Share on Twitter</a>
    <a href="" class="share shareFB" target="_blank">Share on Facebook</a>
    <a href="" class="share shareLI" target="_blank">Share on LinkedIn</a>
    <a href="" class="share shareDE" target="_blank">Share on Delicious</a>
    <a href="" class="share eMail" target="_blank">Send by E-Mail</a>
</span></li>
<li><a class="sharedLink" href="http://www.domain2.com">This is my Tech Blog</a>
<span class="buttons">
    <a href="" class="share shareTW" target="_blank">Share on Twitter</a>
    <a href="" class="share shareFB" target="_blank">Share on Facebook</a>
    <a href="" class="share shareLI" target="_blank">Share on LinkedIn</a>
    <a href="" class="share shareDE" target="_blank">Share on Delicious</a>
    <a href="" class="share eMail" target="_blank">Send by E-Mail</a>
</span></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Meanwhile, I found a way, other then one James proposed, see bellow, here it is: $(this).parents('a');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).closest('li').find('a:first');
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().prev().attr('href');
```

Comment: Yes it does. My guess is that you didn't close the `<a>` tag for `<a class="sharedLink">`. I'm assuming that because it's the only way your comment about `$(this).parents('a')` being a solution would work. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/9G26x/1/